# expect script to scp via an intermediate host

Tags: scp, expect

I found a command to directly scp my file to a host (C) via another host (B) from my computer. The command is in this form:

```
scp -oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p B" thefile C:destination
```

I used it and it works good in command line. but when I want to write an expect script using this command, I got some errors. the script I've written is in this form:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set arg1 [lindex $argv 0]

spawn scp -oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p B" ./$arg1 C:destination 

interact
```

and the error is:

```
unknown option -- W
```

`W` option works in command line but not in expect script. Can anybody tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much easier would be to configure this in the `~/.ssh/config`, where you don't need to care about the syntax of the expect scripts and its issues with arguments. Create `~/.ssh/config` with this content:

```
Host C
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p B
```

and then connect just using

```
spawn scp ./$arg1 C:destination
```

Or just use the simplified version using `ProxyJump` option:

```
spawn scp -oProxyJump=B ./$arg1 C:destination
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But there are some strange problems.  I made the file you mentioned (~/.ssh/config)
as you said. When I execute the command "scp -oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p B" myfile C:destination" in terminal 
it works very well, But when I execute this one: scp myfile C:destination (after creating ~/.ssh/config) I get 
the following error:

channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
stdio forwarding failed
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host 
lost connection

Comment: I searched for this error in forums and they say the intermediate host (B) doesn't allow this process. But how is
it possible when I can execute the command "scp -oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p B" myfile C:destination" directly?!!!

Comment: That is weird. Are you sute you put the hostnames correctly?